# Copy .strings failed to remove

Tags: localization, build, xcode4.2

I get such errors time to time in Xcode 4.2. It appears every time after Product/Clean. I have 15 different languages in Localizable.strings. After 2-3 tries to build apps error disappears! So I can live with it, but it is a bit annoying.

```
error: failed to remove /Users/mikhailkeskinov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dictionary-eiyrziajmltuglfzgtnjxffkojwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dictionary.app/nl.lproj/Localizable.strings: “Localizable.strings” couldn’t be removed.
```

[image]

[image]

**EDITED:** The same problem with XCode 4.3. After every "clear" (or changing any strings) project build successfully after 4-5 tries.

Comment: Check permissions on your *.strings and try to manually delete all your Derived Data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to press 'Validate Settings' in your project settings. I had the same problem and after validation XCode found what there are duplicate entries for resources (in one of build phases). XCode removed them and all problems gone.

Comment: I love how Xcode produces all kinds of stupid errors.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Vitaly S.'s answer, go to Editor --> Validate Settings and one of the suggested fixes should mention `Localization.strings`

[image: Validate Settings]